# Report Viewer does not show report

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I am trying to make a report using this code, but the report shows no data, only blank white form.

What is wrong with this code ? i also tried to use report wizard. the report run well in my computer but when i install my application in other computer, an error message show that "cant find database file". All other datagrid view that use the same database running well. please helo

```
Public Class rpPaket
Dim strConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database2.accdb"
Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim objCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim objDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim objDataTable As DataTable
Dim Report As ReportDataSource

Private Sub rpPaket_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
    objCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from TbPaket", objConnection)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

    'Initialize the DataAdapter object and set the SelectCommand property
    objDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = objCommand

    'Initialize the DataTable object
    objDataTable = New DataTable
    Dim DataSet1 As Database2DataSet8.TbPaketDataTable = New Database2DataSet8.TbPaketDataTable
    'Populate the DataTable
    objDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet1)


    ' Dim ReportDataSource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1_WORKORDERDataTable", CType(DataSet1, DataTable))
    'ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    'ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource)

    Dim adaptar As New Database2DataSet8TableAdapters.TbPaketTableAdapter
    Dim paket_tbl As New Database2DataSet8.TbPaketDataTable
    adaptar.Fill(paket_tbl)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", paket_tbl.DefaultView))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\Report3.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: It seems that objDataTable is unused but this is not the problem. Verify if DataTable DataSet1 contains rows before add it to DataSources. Also, have you set ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath using designer?

Comment: I have tried to use report wizard. It run well in my computer, but when i install my application in other computer, the report turns error cant find database file. Other datagridview that use the same database running well. Where should i change the report path in report wizard?

Comment: I have tried to use report wizard. It run well in my computer, but when i install my application in other computer, the report turns error cant find database file. Other datagridview that use the same database running well. Where should i change the report path in report wizard?

Comment: here is my full code, please check